# Complex class [PrintMax]

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, complex-numbers

So I am working on "TEMPLATES" and I'm required to make a 3 attempt of a function called PrintMax -it's obvious what it does-, to print the maximum element in an array of 3 elements, each attempt is for a different data type in this array -double/int/complex-. So I'm required to first, create the class Complex, and its required operator overloads, after that I use the PrintMax function as template function to work on the 3 types of arrays.

The problem here lies within the 3rd array of course, I can't write the elements of Complex into the array in this for ( a + bi ), because this is my class Complex :

```
    class Complex
{
private :
    int imaginary;
    int real;
public:
    Complex (int = 0, int = 0);
    ~Complex ();
    int getImaginary();
    int getReal();
    void setImagniary(int i);
    void setReal (int r);
    bool operator > (Complex&);
};
```

You can notice, I overloaded operator > to check, but I also have a little problem besides not being able to write the elements in that way, the second problem is I can't -or sleepy and my brain is dying- calculate which is maximum in this array of Complex numbers :

```
// Input: Complex Array
// 1+3i, 2+4i, 3+3i
// Expected Output: 2+4i
```

So I want to assign them in the array with this form : Arr[3] = {1+3i, 2+4i, 3+3i};

Why is that the expected output, why not 3+3i ?

Thanks for reading ~

Comment: Maybe I am confused but 2+4i *is* bigger than 3+3i if you are measuring the absolute value.  See http://www.math.pitt.edu/~sparling/23014/23014notes6/node29.html

Comment: While the greater than operator can be used, normally the less than operator is overloaded because the standard library algorithms use the less than operator.

Comment: Ok, I just want to assign them to an array in that form written above, so that it looks like that Arr[3]={1+3i, 2+4i, 3+3i}

Comment: For avoiding duplicate, you could consider the standard `std::complex` .

Comment: It depends.  If you have a compiler that supports c++11 then you have numeric suffixes so you could define i that way, but then you would also have std::complex so are you allowed to make your own numeric suffix or is this being done with a c++03 compiler.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are looking for something like:

```
template <typename T> void PrintMax(T array[])
{
   // It is assumed that array has 3 elements in it.
   std::cout <<
      array[0] > array[1] ?
        (array[0] > array[2] ? array[0] : array[2]) :
        (array[1] > array[2] ? array[1] : array[2])
        std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I want to ADD the elements in it, I already created the function !

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like the following. Note that there are no range checks in the code, it is just to demonstrate a way how you could solve your problem.

Plus i would suggest you to use a container (eg. `std::vector`) instead of plain arrays.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

class Complex {
private:
    int imaginary;
    int real;
public:    
    Complex(int r, int i) :
            imaginary(i), real(r) {
    }

    ~Complex() {
    }

    int getImaginary() const {
        return imaginary;
    }

    int getReal() const {
        return real;
    }

    void setImaginary(int i) {
        imaginary = i;
    }

    void setReal(int r) {
        real = r;
    }

    double getAbsolut() const {
        return std::abs(std::sqrt(std::pow(imaginary, 2) + std::pow(real, 2)));
    }

    friend bool operator<(const Complex& lhs, const Complex& rhs);
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream,
            const Complex& complex);
};

bool operator<(const Complex& lhs, const Complex& rhs) {
    return lhs.getAbsolut() < rhs.getAbsolut();
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const Complex& complex) {
    stream << "Complex(" << complex.real << "+" << complex.imaginary
            << "i)";
    return stream;
}

template<int size, class T>
void getMax(const T arr[]) {
    T max_value = arr[0];
    for (size_t i = 1; i < size; ++i) {
        max_value = std::max(max_value, arr[i]);
    }
    std::cout << "max: " << max_value << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    Complex arr_complex[] = { Complex(3, 3), Complex(2, 4), Complex(1, 3) };
    int arr_int[] = { 3, 5, 1 };
    double arr_double[] = { 2.3, 5.6, 9.1 };

    getMax<3>(arr_complex);
    getMax<3>(arr_int);
    getMax<3>(arr_double);

    return 0;
}
```